# What do you call someone whose job is to enforce a judge's decision?

Tags: word-request, legalese

In my native country there is a profession whose role is to ensure that a judge's decision is carried out. For example, judge might find the defendant guilty and order him to pay some amount of money to the plaintiff. If the defendant has difficulty paying or refuses to pay then there are people that are tasked with helping resolve the situation. A similar profession must exist throughout the world. What is it called in English?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several such professions in the United States.

- **Bailiffs** and **court clerks** are court employees who issue paperwork on behalf of judges, and keep order in courtrooms.
- **Bounty hunters** collect bounties for retrieving people who "jump bail".
- In many jurisdictions, **sheriff's deputies** can be hired (from the county government) to execute eviction orders.
- **County clerks** and **county recorders** keep track of the official records of property purchases, transfers, easements, and liens.  **Title insurance companies** review these records before issuing insurance policies; banks demand such policies before providing mortgages for property purchases and refinancings.
- **Repo men** steal cars from people who have defaulted on car loans.  They return the "repossessed" cars to the lenders whose names are on the title.
- A **lawyer** or a **collection agency** might send a notice to a garnishee's employer's payroll department or the garnishee's bank, requesting that some of the garnishee's pay be diverted to the garnisher.
- A **building inspector** might issue a stop-work order, telling a builder that he cannot perform any more work at a particular site.  Sometimes the violation has to do with poor quality work, or annoying the neighbors; and sometimes it has to do with failure to pay government fees, obtain building permits, or wait for inspections.

Comment: 'Collection agency' is what I was after. Thank you for your very detailed answer!

Comment: The repo man isn't stealing the car.  Until you pay off the loan, the bank owns the car and agrees to let you use it provided you pay according to the agreed terms.  No different than a mortgage, as evidenced by the fact that the bank keeps the title until you satisfy the loan.